# XOR binary file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, binary

I'm trying to create a "xor" function in Ruby that takes in input a binary file and an hex value and generates a xored binary file in output.

```
File.open("myfile.exe.xor",'w') do |f_xor|
  f_xor.puts File.open("myfile.exe", 'rb').to_i ^ 0xFF
end
```

This code seems not to return the correct xored file as the expected MD5 is different. 
I've been using a XOR command line tool for Linux so far but I want to switch to an OS-agnostic version to also deploy the code on Windows.

Could you help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: At the very least you need to read the bytes from the file (check the file you've just created - it will only be a few bytes long)

Comment: `function` that word is vague, at least in the context of Ruby. What is a function in `Ruby` and how do you create one? That's a good question to ask yourself, though it may not be interesting enough for to ask or you already know the answer, but yet the human mistake is there, you wanted to say `method` instead of `function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `to_i` on a file handle returns the low-level identifier for it, a singular number, nothing more.

If you want to operate on the bytes themselves:

```
File.open(input_file, 'rb') do |f|
  File.open(output_file, 'wb') do |o|
    o.write(
      f.read.bytes.collect do |byte|
        byte ^ xor_value
      end.pack("C*")
    )
  end
end
```

The key here is to apply the XOR operation on each of the bytes in the file, then write out that result. Using `puts` is a mistake since it appends a linefeed.

Comment: Thank you very much @tadman! that worked nicely! Realized about the `puts` mistake instead of `write`.